# Как автоматически подгружать в сайдбар сайта новые опросы без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: wordpress, ajax

создаем на Вордпресс сайте страницу для онлайн трансляции конференции. Страница должна работать так, чтобы при открытии данной страницы посетителем сайта, контент на этой странице автоматически подгружался без перезагрузки самой страницы.

В правой колонке будет этот чат "Wise Chat Pro". В центральной колонке будет видео плеер, для просмотра трансляции из Ютуб, а под ним будет размещаться блок, в котором можно задать вопрос спикеру конференции и сами вопросы будут автоматически появляться без перезагрузки страницы, как в этом примере: https://themes.webberwebber.com/live-neutral/live-relation-directly-from-an-imporant-event/. Как это реализовать понятно, с помощью комментариев к странице и автоматически по аякс подгружать их

Проблема чтобы в левой колонке сайта также как и внизу центральной колонки при публикации новой цитаты или опроса они автоматически подгружались на странице, без перезагрузки самой страницы.

Есть ли возможность подгружать без перезагрузки страницы в сайдбар страницы Вордпресс сайта новые цитаты и опросы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте в js бесконечный цикл с timeout. В нём посылайте ajax  к серверу с запросом текущих цитат, вопросов и комментариев.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, беретесь ли вы за разработку подобных задач? Как с вами связаться для обсуждения бюджета и сроков?

Comment: Недавно делал подобное. А контакты мои в профиле.

Comment: Вижу, что и на WordPress Development вам никто не ответил)